# Django 1.10.6 - Middleware does not work

Tags: python, django

I'm moving my app from django 1.5 to 1.10 and I don't know why but one of my middlewares doesn't want to work ( there is not problem in django 1.5 )

code from settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'myApp.usersAuth.usersAuth',
]
```

Middleware file - usersAuth.py:

```
class usersAuth():
    def test(self, request):
        request.session['firstName'] = 'test1'
        request.session['secondName'] = 'test2'
```

and I see an error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Comment: take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do old style middlewares by inheriting `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin` like

```
class OldMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    #rest of code.
```